# ES6 Найти индексы повторяющихся элементов(строк) в массиве

Tags: javascript

У меня есть следующий массив: `['test', 't', 'test', 'u']`. В массиве могут быть только строки.

Мне нужно узнать индексы всех повторяющихся элементов. В конкретном примере, это 0 и 2.

Какое есть оптимальное решение, используя ES6?

Спасибо!

Comment: большой массив-то? где ваши наброски?

Comment: @teran Массив максимум из 4 элементов.

Answer (score 0):

В общем случае можно решить как-то так, а для 4х элементов мб и проще придумать можно

```js
const data = ['test', 't', 'test', 'u'];

let obj = data.reduce((acc, v, i) => ( 
                v in acc ? acc[v].push(i): acc[v] = [i], acc), {}
              );
let dup = Object.entries(obj)
                .filter(e => e[1].length > 1);

console.log(dup)
```